# Executing code whilst waiting for a context cancel

Tags: go, goroutine

Let's say I have a bunch of goroutines running that do a HTTP request and will return at a random time. I start the goroutines (with waitgroups and one cancel among them) and I want them to keep executing the request until it returns an OK (may time out). When the first one returns, it calls the cancel and every other goroutine should just stop.

I'm not sure how I can set up the goroutine function case that will execute the code if context is not done?

As an example, I know how to use `time.After()` but how do I make it such that it executes the code immediately instead of after a duration?

```
for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            wg.Done()
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            // code goes here
        }
    }
```

What can I replace the time case with?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have multiple goroutines racing to compute the result to the same request. I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
for {
  select {
  case <-ctx.Done():
    wg.Done()
    return
  default:
  }
  // Do stuff
}
```

The select will immediately drop to default if context is not canceled. However, context may still cancel while you're running your code, so you may end up with multiple goroutines trying to write the result, so you have to synchronize that as well. You can write your result to a channel, and when received, you can cancel the context. However you may still have goroutines waiting to write to that channel, so you have to keep reading from the channel until all goroutines terminate.

Comment: That's right. The first goroutine that gets the result will call cancel on the others. I guess the problem we have is that cancel is checked only when the HTTP request returns (either completes, times out, etc.). It's not possible to check whether a channel is already full, without reading it? To prevent having to write more than one thing into the channel

Comment: You should do the cancellation on the receiving end, that is, when the waiting goroutine receives the first result. And after cancelling, it should still read from that channel until all other goroutines terminate, otherwise you'll leak them